# Flying Saucer ignores embedded font when generating PDF

Tags: pdf, itext, flying-saucer

I try to generate PDF using Flying Saucer for the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
  @font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src:url(data:application/font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,d09GRgABAAAAAGSwABMAAAAAtfwAAQAAAAA...zubbzBiN9B2+6bK8AAAABV9JwXgAA) format('woff');
  -fs-pdf-font-embed: embed;
  -fs-pdf-font-encoding: Identity-H;
}

    body {
      font-family: Roboto;
      font-size: 26px;
      font-weight: 300;
      letter-spacing: -.03em;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p>
</body>
</html>
```

where the base64 font is taken from https://gist.github.com/abelaska/9c9eda70d31315f27a564be2ee490cf4

```
        ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
        renderer.setDocumentFromString(data);
        renderer.layout();
        renderer.createPDF(os);
```

When I check the fonts being used in the Properties from Adobe Reader, Times New Roman is listed instead of the font above.

If I use path to the font instead in the css, the PDF correctly shows the font.

```
src:url(/usr/local/Roboto.woff)
```

Can someone let me know what I am missing, or is this Flying Saucer limitation?

Answer (score -1):

Flying saucer uses iText (but not the latest version) under the hood.
A lot of font and HTML related issues were solved in iText7, that was actually a large part of why we moved to iText7 in the first place.

Try pdfHTML. It's an iText7 add-on that allows you to convert HTML5 (+CSS3) to PDF. It's AGPL licensed and open source. (Or rather, we are currently in the process of open sourcing it).

https://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfHTML

This is some example code:

```
// load license
LicenseKey.loadLicenseFile("path_to_license_key.xml");

// conversion
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(
    "<b>This text should be written in bold.</b>", 
    new PdfWriter(new File("C://users/user5733033/output.pdf"))
);
```

Comment: I was expecting Flying Saucer solution since it is what we have been using it for our project.

Comment: I am certainly not saying this is **the** solution to your problem. I am merely solving the underlying problem.